# Pycharm: disable copy on select text

Tags: pycharm, copy-paste

Scenario: I am trying to copy something **into** Pycharm. When accidentally selecting something (even an empty line) in Pycharm, it gets copied and overwrites the buffer.
Pasting then pastes the empty line (or whatever got selected) instead of what I copied originally.

Is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to open the settings. Type "copy" into the search bar. Disable this checkbox:

[image: PyCharm Settings]

Comment: This doesn't work for me, is there a way to make it work in the editor? (could it be related to the fact that Pycharm runs on a remote server and I'm copying from the local computer?)

Answer (score 7):

If you launch Pycharm using XServer, then the following worked for me ([ref](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206600405-PyCharm-on-Linux-How-to-disable-Select-to-Copy-Feature)):

> After experiencing the same problem on VcXsrv X server on Windows
> (which is a fork of Xming), the solution was to cancel the "Clipboard
> my use primary selection" option in VcXsrv tray icon context menu.
>
> From the youtrack issue it looks like it was always an X server configuration problem.

I have also disabled **Settings | Tools | Terminal | Copy to clipboard of selection** option.

Comment: This weird edge case was very close to the source of my problem.  You also need to 'Reload .XWinRC' in my case - Cygwin running Xming.

Answer (score 0):

To get the history of the clipboard press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> or go to `Edit` > `Paste from History`,

This opens a dialog with previous copies which looks like this,

[image: clipboard history PyCharm]

from the top box, select the relevant copy and press ok.

Answer (score 0):

Using solution suggested by @Saim Raza in Xming itself. Disabling X11 Primary Selection by right clicking Xming icon in windows system tray worked for me. This can be automated by creating a .cmd file in which Xming.exe is invoked with -clipboard **-noprimary** arguments (found from [Xming Manual](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/manual.php)). I have created file Xming_Wrapper.cmd in my Desktop with following commands

```
start "Xming" "Substitute Path of Xming.exe e.g. %PROGRAMFILES%\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -noprimary -multiwindows -dpi 144 -ac
exit %errorlevel%
```

I am able to paste text copied from windows in Pycharm started via Xming. Before I used to get problem in find tabs of Pycharm when text was already present content copied from windows was overriden. Selecting text in Pycharm no longer overrides contents copied from windows.

I have also incorporated solution suggested by @Ian i.e. accepted answer

I am using Xming 7.7.0.59

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Saim Raza's answer, for those using **MobaXTerm**, you can disable primary copy selection like so :

`Settings` > `X11` > `X11 settings` > `Clipboard` > select `disable primary`

Don't forget to restart the server !

NB : PyCharm only allows disabling copy on selection **in the terminal**. Solutions mentionning this won't resolve this topic's issue.