# How to use copy and paste with selection + middle MB in PyCharm Editor?

Tags: pycharm, copy-paste

After [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007903/pycharm-disable-copy-on-select-text) where somebody asked how to disable this behaviour, I noticed that my PyCharm does not behave like that at all.

I have the options to copy and paste using text selection and middle mouse button in the terminal (which works fine). How can I use that same method in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something you have to do with the keymap:

- Ctrl + Alt + S (settings).
- Keymap.
- In search bar type "paste".
- Look for an option named "Paste".
- Right click it then choose "Add Mouse Shortcut".
- Press the middle mouse button then click "Ok"

It should prompt you that the same key is assigned to another action. (For me the action is "Paste From X Clipboard", and "Declaration")

I still haven't found a way to highlight the text and copy it to the clipboard automatically, but if I found an option like that I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like there is no solution to the second part of the problem.. anyway, you get the green check mark!